# Azure Portal Function Error: Update your NuGet package reference for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I've been trying to fix this since yesterday but have done more damage than good. I have a function app (written in JS) in the Azure Portal. All was working well until two days ago when I received the below error. I've seen a few bits online saying the fix is to update the reference however I'm not really sure where I should update the reference to NuGet package.
In my function app's code I have both a js file and the json file but I don't know where the NuGet package comes in. Apologies if this is trivial I'm still learning but would really like to understand what's going on here.
For reference I'm on a Mac and have been working off VS code.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more loaded extensions do not meet the minimum requirements. For more information see https://aka.ms/func-min-extension-versions.
>
> ExtensionStartupType EventHubsWebJobsStartup from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not meet the required minimum version of 4.3.0.0. Update your NuGet package reference for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs to 4.3.0 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few of the workaround to update the NuGet Packages were:**

***Way 1: Using NuGet Package Manager***

Right Click on your project in Visual Studio > Select Manage NuGet Packages Option > Click on Updates > You'll find the Packages if any new versions are available for Update.
[image]

***Way 2: Using Command Line/Terminal***
**If you're using Visual Studio IDE, to open the terminal:**

[image]

Using this [NuGet Official Site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs/) , you can find the command here to install from the NuGet Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs -Version 5.0.0
```

If you're using Visual Studio Code IDE, then open the terminal and install/update the required packages using this command and this command will be available in the above site only:

[image]

The Command is:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs --version 5.0.0
```

**Way 3:**

Open the **Command Prompt** > drive to your **project path** located > Use the above ***.Net Core CLI Command*** to install the required packages like:

[image]

**Way 4:**

Go to [NuGet Official Site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs/) > Find the latest version of the required package > Copy the Package Reference code and replace the existing old version package reference code from the **`.csproj`** file:

[image]

Double-click the Project Name (1) in the solution explorer to open `.csproj` file and include the latest package reference of the required package like below:

[image]

**Note:**

***1. To download the specific version of the required packages, go to the **versions** option available on the same official site of the package like below:***

[image]

2. ***If it specifically asks for updating the extension bundles, then you can refer to this [Extension Bundle Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles) to include the given code in the `Host.json` file of your Azure Functions Project.***

Comment: Thank you again all for your help! Beautiful. Really appreciate you taking the time to write this out.

Answer (score 3):

In host.json, use the latest 3.x [extension bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles):

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers man. Really appreciate the help